# How can I convert a single Object of objects, into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am retrieving an list of books from my Firebase database, where each "book" is an object.

***The payload of books, is one monolithic object of objects as such:***

```
{ 
      key1: { 
       "title": "A Good Book"
       "author": "A Person"
      },
      key2: {
       "title": "Another Good Book"
       "author": "Another person"
      }
     ...and so on
    }
```

I need to change that monolithic object into an array of objects, so that I can map through each and extract the values I want.

***The expected array that I need:***

```
    [
       { 
         "title": "A Good Book"
         "author": "A Person"
       },
       {
         "title": "Another Good Book"
         "author": "Another person"
       }
    ]
```

I've tried using `Object.entries(myObject)` and `Object.values(myObject)` but this just returns garbled metadata about the object.

I've tried other answers from stack overflow such as this:

```
    var array = Object.entries(data).map(([phrase, date]) => ({phrase,date}));
```

But this doesn't work.

I initially thought this should be straightforward and common issue, but after combing through stack overflow and google for a few days, I have not encountered a similar problem & solution.

Comment: Your first snippet does not contain valid object literal syntax. How does your object really look? An object without keys isn't really an object.

Comment: If your data is a JSON Object, then use jacksons Object mapper. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Comment: @Bergi is correct, you can't create an object without a key, In your case, It might like this `{ '0': {}, '1': {} }`

Comment: All - I've updated the object syntax to more closely reflect what my object(s) look like. The "key" in this instance is in fact the title of the book. @Bergi

Comment: @jmedran For that object, `Object.values` should work fine. What "*garbled metadata about the object*" do you see?

Comment: @Dasarathan This is javascript, not java.

Comment: @Bergi `console.log(Object.values(myObject))` returns a gigantic nested object with stuff such as "LazyHash", "priorityNode", "indexMap" etc. Not sure what all of that is.

Comment: @jmedran What does `console.log(myObject)` log? Is it plain data, is it an instance of some class? Notice that `Object.values` should never return a gigantic object, but always an array.

Comment: @Bergi `console.log(myObject)` returns plain data (JSON). The payload is a _"static snapshot"_ of the path I am referencing to my Firebase Database. See this link for Google's simple explanation: [Reading From Firebase DB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#reading_and_writing_data). So `myObject` is actually the `snapshot` value you see in the docs.

Comment: @jmedran The snapshot paylod is everything but a plain data object, it's a `Snapshot` instance! "*You can retrieve the data in the snapshot with the `.val()` method.*".

Comment: @Bergi You are correct! Frankly, this was the root of all my issues, by not having the`snapshot.val()` method. Quite embarrassing I missed that in the docs. Thank you helping me through this issue!

Answer (score 0):

There must be some keys in any object like this(i edited them):

```
    let data = { 
       { 
      "Harry Potter": {
          "BookInfo": { 
               "Pages": 500,
               "Author": "JK Rowling"
           },
          "SaleInfo": "For Sale"
      },
     "A Clockwork Orange": {
           "BookInfo": { 
               "Pages": 200,
               "Author": "Anthony Burgess"
           },
          "SaleInfo": "For Sale"
      }
    }
     ...and so on
    }
```

if so then you can use `Object.valus()` as:

```
const books =  { 
      "Harry Potter": {
          "BookInfo": { 
               "Pages": 500,
               "Author": "JK Rowling"
           },
          "SaleInfo": "For Sale"
      },
     "A Clockwork Orange": {
           "BookInfo": { 
               "Pages": 200,
               "Author": "Anthony Burgess"
           },
          "SaleInfo": "For Sale"
      }
     ...
    }
const booksMapped = Object.keys(books).map(bookName => {
  return {
    bookName,
    ...books[bookName]
  }
})

console.log(booksMapped)
/*
[
  {
    "bookName": "Harry Potter",
    "BookInfo": {
      "Pages": 500,
      "Author": "JK Rowling"
    },
    "SaleInfo": "For Sale"
  },
  {
    "bookName": "A Clockwork Orange",
    "BookInfo": {
      "Pages": 200,
      "Author": "Anthony Burgess"
    },
    "SaleInfo": "For Sale"
  }
]
*/
```

basically `Object.keys()` will give you an array with every keys given object and then you can chain any array method on it
eg:
**map**
**reduce**
**forEach**
**filter**
**find**
etc

```
let person {
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 18
}

Object.keys(person) // => ["name", "age"]
Object.values(person) // => ["John Doe", 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object to get an array of objects:

```js
const input = {
  "Harry Potter": {
    BookInfo: { Pages: 500, Author: "JK Rowling" },
    SaleInfo: "For Sale",
  },
  "A Clockwork Orange": {
    BookInfo: { Pages: 200, Author: "Anthony Burgess" },
    SaleInfo: "For Sale",
  }
};

const output = Object.entries(input).map(([title, value ]) => ({
  title,
  author: value.BookInfo.Author
}))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution is to use flatMap():

```
const sorce = { 
      key1: { 
       "title": "A Good Book",
       "author": "A Person"
      },
      key2: {
       "title": "Another Good Book",
       "author": "Another person"
      }
    };

const result = Object.keys(sorce).flatMap(key => sorce[key]);
console.log(result);
```

> Result: 
>   [ 
>   { title: 'A Good Book', author: 'A Person' },
>   { title:'Another Good Book', author: 'Another person' } 
>   ]

P.S. We can use map at this case with the same result:

```
const result = Object.keys(sorce).map(key => sorce[key]);
```